# How do I insert an image in a DataGridView from database table?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms

Hey Everyone I am new to C#.
Can anyone tell me how to insert an image in a DataGriVview cell from MySQL Database?

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products", con);
        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ViewAlldataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
    }
}
```

I tried to select image but got error:

[image: ERROR Image]

I hope I have given sufficient information to solve.

EDIT:
the data type is blob for images
[Datatype Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbzTL.jpg)

Comment: The error is saying that the column in the grid is an `Image` column and the data in the `DataSource` bound to that column is NOT an `Image` type object. It would appear the code is adding the columns manually in the designer or code. Have you checked what type the image column is in the DB? Are you sure it isn’t a `string` path to the image instead of the image itself?

Comment: Post the Data Type of the `photo` and `qrcode` Columns. If you stored those Image in code, post the code that is doing that, plus the format of those Images.

Comment: @Jimi i have updated the question please check and the data type of image is blob

Comment: @JohnG hey john i have edited the question pleas check the data type

Comment: Can you show the column type in the DB for the two image columns? It appears the images are stored as “Blob”s which could be anything. I will assume you need some conversion from the blob to an image. It seems fairly clear the `DataGridView` does not know how to handle a “Blob” object.

Comment: @JohnG so which type it should be